# How can I deserialize this JSON with JsonConvert?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this JSON and I cannot figure out how to convert it to a List of objects in C#.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "2": {
    "sell_average": 239,
    "buy_average": 238,
    "overall_average": 240,
    "id": 2
  },
  "6": {
    "sell_average": 184434,
    "buy_average": 182151,
    "overall_average": 189000,
    "id": 6
  },
  "8": {
    "sell_average": 11201,
    "buy_average": 1723,
    "overall_average": 180,
    "id": 8
  }
}
```

And the code I've tried using:

```
public class ItemSummaryModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ItemSummary ItemSummary { get; set; }
}

public class ItemSummary
{
    public int Sell_Average { get; set; }
    public int Buy_Average { get; set; }
    public int Overall_Average { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

List<ItemSummaryModel> models =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemSummaryModel>>(jsonSummary);
```

to no avail.  How can I deserialize this JSON into lists of these objects using Newtonsoft's JSON library (Json.Net)?

Comment: A couple of things to consider: you're attempting to deserialize to a list but your JSON does not represent a list, it's just a complex object with properties. Secondly, your domain object property names don't match the JSON property names, so much of the C# needs to be decorated with attributes that specify the exact name in the JSON. Lastly, there's nothing to indicate that "2", "6", and "8" are "Id"s, so at the moment your JSON structure is not equivalent to the C# structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, ItemSummary>>(json);
var items = dict.Values.ToList();  //if you want a List<ItemSummary>;
```

Comment: Using Dictionary<string, ItemSummary> because string id eg "2" in JSON string can not convert to int

Comment: @VuDang Trust me, JSON.NET is more clever than expected.

Comment: That's... really elegant. I like it a lot. JSON.NET never fails to impress.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ItemSummaryModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "2")]
    public ItemSummary Two { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "6")]
    public ItemSummary Six { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "8")]
    public ItemSummary Eight { get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemSummaryModel>(json);
```

This will technically work to get you a complex object, but I don't much like it. Having numbers for property names is going to be an issue. This being json for a single complex object will also be tricky. If it were instead a list, you could begin writing your own ContractResolver to handle mapping the number property name to an id field and the actual object to whatever property you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The only problem with this is that there are a total of roughly 40,000 objects. Do you think that it would be easier to possible convert the JSON to a list after I received it? I have no control over the JSON being output.